# Cloned directly from repo...get error when pushing

Tags: git, github

Cloned a repo, commited, and when I go to push I get an error:

`remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/USER/REPO.git/' not found`

Anyone have an idea what might be causing this? I've checked the remote and it is correct (I cloned and didn't touch it after).

Comment: Please add: 1) Exactly how you originally cloned the repo (commands, etc), 2) Your current directory (`pwd`) when trying this.

Comment: used:
``` git clone URL ``` 
and i'm in the main directory.

Comment: Thanks.  Please do `pwd`, I'm not totally sure what main directory means.  Trying to help :)

Comment: Is this your own repo or are you looking to fork someone else's?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I figured out the problem, thanks. It isn't my repository. I didn't have write access to the main repo

Comment: I suspected as much.  You may find my forking answer works for u then.  'scuse the pun ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to add a file to the repo directly from Github (via the add file button) and was told I didn't have write access...problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

In case you are trying to fork someone else's repo:

fork it (in github, using a browser) and then go to **your** github account and the fork.  Clone that (use the button in browser) and git clone **that repo**.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue when cloning the repo.
Below is the error message

"ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights"

I changed the clone URL to https and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was always a permission issue which led to this error. Here are the steps to add permission to a user,

1. Login into GitHub website as administrator
2. Click on the "Your Profile" link from the Icon menu in top right corner
3. Click on your Organization Icon displayed on the left hand side
4. Click the "People" tab.
5. Click on the corresponding user link
6. Change Read Privilege to Write Privilege