# What does the Git error "remote: Repository not found." mean?

Tags: github

After I issued

```
git push origin <branch-name>
```

and entered the access credentials, Git returned an error like so

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/<account-name>/<repository-name>.git'
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cloned directly from repo...get error when pushing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777122/cloned-directly-from-repo-get-error-when-pushing)

Comment: possible duplicate of [GitHub Error: Repository Not Found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184433/github-error-repository-not-found)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The GitHub help page, "[Error: Repository not found](https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found)" summarizes the possible causes:

- permission (which is what [Monika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2909797/monika) refers to in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971049/what-does-the-git-error-remote-repository-not-found-mean#comment29728547_19971049) with "[Cloned directly from repo…get error when pushing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19777122/6309)")

  You might need to **[fork the repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6286877/6309)**, and, on your local repo, do a:

  ```
  git remote rename origin upstream
  git remote add origin https://YourUsername@github.com/YourUsername/YourFork
  ```
- spelling: the name of the repo is **[case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6650488/6309)**
- non-existent repo

Comment: Tracking URLs don't count as referrals when linked to from a Stack Exchange site

Comment: For the third case "non-existant repo", i'm thinking to myself, "Yeah, i know i want to create one remotely." Any thoughts?

Comment: @RobbieSmith yes, you can create on in command-line through the GitHub API: http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create

Comment: i ended up creating a php script on the remote server to make the dir and do a git init --bare. THEN i could do the git push -u origin master stuff.. Duh moment, it's it plugged in.

Comment: Actually in my case this was caused by having two github accounts/users - and git (CLI) was trying to use the wrong user when committing (hence the permission problem)