# git clone: repo is not there

Tags: git, github, clone

I am having an issue with github repo. I have forked the private repo and trying to clone it and it's not working.

```
"remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository https://github.com/MYUSERNAME/MYREPO.git/' not found

Tried git clone https://github.com/username/repo
git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git
fatal: repository https://github.com/MYUSERNAME:PASSWORD/USERNAME/MYREPO.git/' not found
```

Without Quotes around it.
Still getting errors. Any help?

Comment: check out this link: https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found/

Comment: Thanks all, I've set up SSH and it worked via SSH. Wonder what the issue was with HTTPS

Comment: I'm just starting to use private repos (and Git/GitHub in general), does that mean HTTPS doesn't work with private repos and I have to use SSH? I think it's unlikely to be the case, but just wanted to check.   I've used HTTPS with public repos and it's worked fine (and I'm ok with it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the Git error "remote: Repository not found." mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971049/what-does-the-git-error-remote-repository-not-found-mean)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need quotes to clone.
But it will be better to use ssh instead since you will not be prompt for password for pull & push.

[image]
[image]

---

#### How to add ssh key to github account?

- Login to github account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (Settings)
  [image: github account settigns]
- Click on the `SSH keys`
  [image: ssh key section]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image: Add ssh key]
- Paste your key and save

And you all set to go :-)